# Accessing images in GitHub folders from Python

Tags: python, github

I have images I would like to use for an application I built via Kivy. There are a bunch of them (50+) so I organized my GitHub folder into two separate folders - 'images' and 'code'.

However, when I run this program locally, they're all sitting in the same directory so I can simply run something like the following:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('testimage.png')
image.show()
```

In my GitHub repo, `images` is a subfolder of `code`. What I'm trying to be able to achieve is someone using a `makefile` I have in the repo to run the entire program and have the images found. Something like this from the command line `python3 test_program.py`.

However, even though `images` is a subfolder of `code`, the following does not work: `image = Image.open('images\\testimage.png')`. I'm guessing it's because the path is no longer right when cloning the repo and trying to run the program through command line. **How can I point to these images in my program if they're in another GitHub folder?**

My folder structure looks like this:

```
+ Main GitHub Repo
    + Code Folder
       - test_project.py
       + Images Folder
          - testimage.png
```

Alternatively, my professor really wanted the `images` and `code` to be on the same level (shown below), but I would just like it to work, so whatever you guys think is easiest to do, I'm willing to shuffle the structure.

```
+ Main GitHub Repo
    + Code Folder
       - test_project.py
    + Images Folder
       - testimage.png
```

Not sure I described it in the best way, but if anything is unclear, please let me know and I will try to clarify. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please add your github folder structure, lets say

---code 
-------images
to have a clearly perspective

Comment: Just added - thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('./Images\ Folder/testimage.png')
image.show()
```

Also if you change folder names to do not have special characters it will be easier to use, let's say renaming Images Folder to Images_folder

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('./Images_folder/testimage.png')
image.show()
```

Comment: Exactly!! Very impressive. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped.